# Cache is not updating in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, browser-cache

1. I loaded `jquery.min.js` in head tag using script tag as below. this version was 1.2.6.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js?v=1.2.6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

2. Then I cleared cache and loaded page (that one is ASPX)
3. So above `jquery.min.js?v=1.2.6` is cached in browser now.
4. Migrate plugin is 3.0.0 which has issue with this version of jQuery.
5. So I changed content of (I know I can use different path anyway) `jquery.min.js` from 3.2.1 jQuery file and script tag changed to

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1"></script>
```

6. I reloaded same page at that time also it gives error of migrate plugin. in console also error is in `JS/jquery.min.js?v=1.2.6`
7. When I reload it second time (without clearing cache) , then it is not showing error anymore and also if I clear cache at first time then also error is not present.

What's wrong am I doing?

Here it doesn't matter which error it is but only matters is why it is occurring even after querystring is different.

Comment: Are you really using jQuery 1.2.6?

Comment: Actually. We had old codes to upgrade. Some elder people did it. :)

Comment: if you change the querystring then it will get new script first and cache that in browser until querystring is changed so there might be some issue in content you can check from where it is loaded in network tab of chrome or firefox

Comment: In network, it loads fresh one. But don't know still it gives error from old one once.